# Estimation of the $n$-th Gauss integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(\xi_n)_{n\ge0}$ be the sequence of Gauss integers in $\mathbb Z[i]$ situed in the part of plane $\{\arg(z)\in[0,\frac\pi 2]\}$ sorted by non-decreasing modulus. In case of tie, we sort them by non-decreasing arguments. Can one obtain an asymptotic expansion of $|\xi_n|$?

Comment: There's one Gaussian integer per unit square, so the sector $\arg(z)\in[0,\pi/2]$, $|z|<R$ contains approximately $n(R)=\pi R^2/4$ numbers of the sequence with the latest ones near the perimeter $|\xi_{n(R)}|\approx R$. Looks like $|\xi_n|\approx \sqrt{4 n/\pi}$. Somehow I guess that you want something more precise?

Comment: Yes, I think that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|\xi_n-\sqrt{4\pi/n}|\le C$, but I can not prove it.